# BV function as left-continuous decomposition

Tags: real-analysis

A bounded variation (BV) function $f$ on the whole real line can be written as a difference of two monotone increasing function. This can be done by the construction

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} V[0,x] &\mbox{if } x\geq 0 \\
-V[x,0] & \mbox{if } x<0 \end{cases}$$ and $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$, where $V[a,b]$ denote the total variation over the interval $[a,b]$, defined as $$\sup\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})| \text{ with } a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b\right).$$

Now, suppose $f$ is left-continuous (i.e. $f(a^-)=f(a)$ for all $a$) and BV. I want to write $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$, where $g$ and $h$ are monotone increasing, bounded, and left-continuous.

I think this construction achieves $g$ and $h$ being monotone increasing, bounded, but not left-continuous (in the part $x<0$). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $g$ is non-decreasing, and $g-f$ is non-decreasing.

Let $\gamma(x) = \lim_{y \uparrow x} g(y)$. It is straightforward to show that $\gamma$ is left continuous, and non-decreasing.

Let $\eta(x) = \gamma(x)-f(x)$. Note that $\eta(x) = \lim_{y \uparrow x} (g(y)-f(y))$, since $f$ is left continuous, and since $g-f$ is non-decreasing, we see that $\eta$ is non-decreasing. Since both $\gamma$ and $f$ are left continuous, we see that $\eta$ is too.